# I have deployed smart contract successfully, after copying the transaction hash to check info of the token created i found nothing on bscscan

Tags: solidity

I have changed the contract from the drop down menu whether I deploy wrong contract unfortunately its still not showing. I also increased the gas fees. I have tried severally by using different browser and I also used http and https all to no avail
This is one of the transaction hash of the token I created below:
0xbe8e45ca80fae1de52f60addeae7dbdf0ae75778a3e29f185aa628b7faa0bd7f

Comment: On which network did you deploy the contract? I.e. the Remix VM emulator, testnet, ...?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I deployed the contract on Binance smart chain testnet.....

Answer (score 0):

The transaction shows up correctly on the **testnet** BSCScan: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xbe8e45ca80fae1de52f60addeae7dbdf0ae75778a3e29f185aa628b7faa0bd7f

BSCScan distinguishes between the testnet and the mainnet. So a transaction that exists only on testnet, will not show on the mainnet explorer.